# White Flash inbetween Re-rendering Image Views

Tags: react-native

Not sure if this is a huge issue, but I am not completely sure a solution exists to this.

When creating a slideshow style element, where upon tap you image changes to another image (already prefetched using React Native's image prefetcher) there is this white flash when the screen re-renders (I think?).

Has there been a concrete solution to this? I can't figure out how something like say a snapchat story manages to render a new image completely instant

Has anyone ever done this? is the strategy to just load one image on top of another?