# Images flash upon loading

Tags: react-native, fresco

## Description

Upon loading an image (gif/jpg/webp/png) the image flashes the background color then loads the image. I expect that the image would just load and only have a placeholder when the image takes a while to load.
This problem is irrelevant to the size of the image (img size 10kb). Even if the image loads immediately the background color flashes.

## Reproduction

Essentially just load an image and replace it with another image on the same scene.
I have a git project with the issue where it flashes red:
https://github.com/dnam50/gifTry.git

A gif demonstrating https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28775204/32446378-5eb5926e-c311-11e7-9afe-6c689a4280af.gif

Additional Information

Fresco version: [1.5.0]
Platform version: [nexus 6 api 25] but has been tried on numerous android devices.

I am aware of [White Flash inbetween Re-rendering Image Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686416/white-flash-inbetween-re-rendering-image-views) which is the same issue but I have added a code example and gif example.

Thanks

Comment: hi, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: no, we noticed it was because the native library was problematic.